# How to make a table from lists of data?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3 lists of data: time, radius and angle. I want to make a table of these three lists but am not sure how. I want it to look like:

```
time   radius   angle
0.0    3.1      0
0.1    3.0      3
```

And so on. I believe I should make an array somehow but am not sure exactly how to do this. I tried figuring it out using numpy.array or numpy.arange but could not get anything to work.

An example of the input might be

```
print time
[ 0.          0.001001    0.002002    0.003003    0.004004    0.00500501]
print radius
[ 1.          1.00099904  1.00199417  1.00298539  1.00397268  1.00495605]
print angle
[  2.54558441e-01   5.08609013e-01   7.62155215e-01   1.01520052e+00    1.26774839e+00   1.51980226e+00]
```

Also, to clarify, the lists contain hundreds of values.

Comment: By 'make a table' you mean print data as a table?

Comment: any example of the input list?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate might be helpful.

Comment: @GrishaS Yeah, I want to print the data as a table

Comment: @Marcin edited it to include example

Comment: @jakeowen I provided answer for numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help:

```
time_l = [0.  ,        0.001001,    0.002002 ,   0.003003,    0.004004,    0.00500501]
radious_l = [ 1.,          1.00099904 , 1.00199417  ,1.00298539 , 1.00397268,  1.00495605]
angle_l  = [  2.54558441e-01,   5.08609013e-01 ,  7.62155215e-01 ,  1.01520052e+00  ,  1.26774839e+00 ,  1.51980226e+00]



an_array = np.array([time_l, radious_l, angle_l]).T


np.set_printoptions(suppress = True, precision=3)

print(an_array)
```

Result:

```
[[ 0.     1.     0.255]
 [ 0.001  1.001  0.509]
 [ 0.002  1.002  0.762]
 [ 0.003  1.003  1.015]
 [ 0.004  1.004  1.268]
 [ 0.005  1.005  1.52 ]]
[[ 0.255  1.     0.   ]
 [ 0.509  1.001  0.001]
 [ 0.762  1.002  0.002]
 [ 1.015  1.003  0.003]
 [ 1.268  1.004  0.004]
 [ 1.52   1.005  0.005]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the values in decimal notation instead of scientific?

Comment: @jakeowen I amended the anwser.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you, one last thing: how can I make the output not give me a ...
>> [[   0.              1.              0.          ]
 [   0.001001001     1.0009990445    0.5086090132]
 [   0.002002002     1.001994175     0.7621552152]
 ..., 
 [   0.997997998     0.3566079907  218.4123978576]
 [   0.998998999     0.3572850501  220.4065478177]
 [   1.              0.3579791659  222.3929720262]]

Comment: @jakeowen sorry, I dont understand. You can use np printoption to modify the printing of arrays to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Zip for it like this:

```
>>> time = ['time',0.0,0.1]
>>> radius=['radius',3.1,3.0]
>>> angle=['angle',0,3]
>>> list = zip(time,radius,angle)
>>> list
[('time', 'radius', 'angle'), (0.0, 3.1, 0), (0.1, 3.0, 3)]
```

Comment: Just edited to clarify that each list actually contains hundreds of values, I just gave a simply example.

Comment: well, it'll work anyway, I just used your example of time, radius, angle, they can have any length

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be

```
>>> times = ['time', 0.0, 0.1]
>>> radius = ['radius', 3.1, 3.0]
>>> angles = ['angle', 0, 3]
>>> data = [times, radius, angles]
>>> data
[['time', 0.0, 0.1], ['radius', 3.1, 3.0], ['angle', 0, 3]]
>>> table = zip(*data)
>>> for row in table:
...     print row
...
('time', 'radius', 'angle')
(0.0, 3.1, 0)
(0.1, 3.0, 3)
```

Since, you say that inputs are large, you could try the below

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for t,r,a in itertools.izip(times, radius, angles):
...     print t, r, a
...
time radius angle
0.0 3.1 0
0.1 3.0 3
>>> for t,r,a in itertools.izip_longest(times, radius, angles):
...     print t, r, a
...
time radius angle
0.0 3.1 0
0.1 3.0 3
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to understand your wish, maybe this will help?

```
time_list = [0.0,0.1]
radius_list = [3.1,3.0]
angle_list = [0,3]

tbl = []
for i in range(len(time_list)):
    temp_var = {}
    temp_var['time'] = time_list[i]
    temp_var['radius'] = radius_list[i]
    temp_var['angle'] = angle_list[i]
    tbl.append(temp_var)
print tbl

print "time\tradius\tangle"
for i in range(len(tbl)):
    print "%s\t%s\t%s" % (tbl[i]['time'],tbl[i]['radius'],tbl[i]['angle'])
```

?